# mysqli object how do I get the fields

Tags: php, mysql, variables, object, mysqli

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM temp_users WHERE reg_code ='$passkey'");

This works:

```
if($result->num_rows == 1){
```

values from print_r($result);

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 11 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )
```

but `$result->username` where username is a field in the db shows up blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because you need to fetch a row from the `$result`. It can be done via function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php and a few more - check PHP manual.

**From manual:**

```
/* associative array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $row["username"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use mysqli_fetch_array or similar.